# What is this graphical effect called?

Tags: transformations, projections

I was watching this trailer:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWh5388AEHw

and at 1:22, the player used a magic trick that created a sphere that warped the projection of the scene.
[image]

Does anyone know what is this effect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don’t think there’s a formally established name for it, but it’s generally known as distortion, warping, or refraction. It works by taking an already rendered version of the current frame, sampling it with warped/stretched texture coordinates, and, usually, compositing the result back in with the rest of the scene. One of the first games I know of that used it was Half-Life 2, for an effect when the Strider enemies fired their cannon:

[image]

For an example of what this looks like in a modern game engine, check out [Unreal’s documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/RenderingAndGraphics/Materials/HowTo/Refraction/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Rasterizers will probably handle it as a post processing effect. While doing ray tracing/marching it's possible to bend the rays while incrementing at each step.